# How to improve a lua filter so that it can customise font colour of pptx documents

Tags: lua, r-markdown, powerpoint, pandoc, quarto

I endeavour to modify the font colour within a pptx document that has been generated from a qmd file utilising a lua filter entitled 'color-text.lua', which is from [5.1 Font color | R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/font-color.html#lua-color).

The lua filter demonstrates proficiency in altering the font colour during the rendering process of HTML-based documents, encompassing standard HTMLs and revealjs presentations, as well as latex-based documents, which encompass PDFs and beamer presentations.

Regrettably, I am uncertain about the methodology to enhance the lua filter's capabilities in order to alter font colour in pptx documents. Any insights or suggestions are appreciated.

[image]

## MWE

### test.qmd

````
---
format:
  pptx:
    keep-md: true
filter:
  - color-text.lua
---

## Slide title 1

First, we define a Lua filter and write it to
the file `color-text.lua`.


```lua
Span = function(span)
  color = span.attributes['color']
  -- if no color attribute, return unchange
  if color == nil then return span end

  -- tranform to <span style="color: red;"></span>
  if FORMAT:match 'html' or FORMAT:match 'revealjs' then
    -- remove color attributes
    span.attributes['color'] = nil
    -- use style attribute instead
    span.attributes['style'] = 'color: ' .. color .. ';'
    -- return full span element
    return span
  elseif FORMAT:match 'latex' or FORMAT:match 'beamer' then
    -- remove color attributes
    span.attributes['color'] = nil
    -- encapsulate in latex code
    table.insert(
      span.content, 1,
      pandoc.RawInline('latex', '\\textcolor{'..color..'}{')
    )
    table.insert(
      span.content,
      pandoc.RawInline('latex', '}')
    )
    -- returns only span content
    return span.content
  else
    -- for other format return unchanged
    return span
  end
end
```

## Slide title 2

Now we can test the filter with some text in brackets with
the `color` attribute, e.g.,

> Roses are [red and **bold**]{color="red"} and
> violets are [blue]{color="blue"}.
````

### color-text.lua

```lua
Span = function(span)
  color = span.attributes['color']
  -- if no color attribute, return unchange
  if color == nil then return span end

  -- tranform to <span style="color: red;"></span>
  if FORMAT:match 'html' or FORMAT:match 'revealjs' then
    -- remove color attributes
    span.attributes['color'] = nil
    -- use style attribute instead
    span.attributes['style'] = 'color: ' .. color .. ';'
    -- return full span element
    return span
  elseif FORMAT:match 'latex' or FORMAT:match 'beamer' then
    -- remove color attributes
    span.attributes['color'] = nil
    -- encapsulate in latex code
    table.insert(
      span.content, 1,
      pandoc.RawInline('latex', '\\textcolor{'..color..'}{')
    )
    table.insert(
      span.content,
      pandoc.RawInline('latex', '}')
    )
    -- returns only span content
    return span.content
  else
    -- for other format return unchanged
    return span
  end
end
```